# strange behavior Chrome extension authentication API rejects 403 error

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Really frustrated. Have to come here and ask for help -

I am developing an extension that will call my own site for data retrieval and, of course, user authentication.
Everything works when developing locally.
However, when I deployed it to the server (using Dreamhost), the authentication part failed miserably. I've spent a couple of days trying to fix it and tried almost every method I can find on the WWW. On the other side, Postman and curl work.

Using Chrome.Identity - I can get an authorization code but then it just won't reach the token part. Throwing 403.

Fetch code is very basic:

```
 let payload = {
          grant_type:'authorization_code',
          code:auth_code,
          redirect_uri:redirectUri,
          client_id:CLIENT_ID,
          client_secret:CLIENT_SECRET        
        }; 
  let new_data = jQuery.param(payload);
  console.log(new_data);
 
  fetch('https://www.heymofas.com/m/oauth2/token',{
    method: 'POST',
    headers:{
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      },
    body: new_data
  })
```

I am attaching the request and response headers here.
Can anyone spot anything that's not normal? Many many thanks.

Request URL: https://www.heymofas.com/m/oauth2/token
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 403 Forbidden
Remote Address: 67.205.8.242:443
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Connection: Upgrade, Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date: Sun, 12 Jul 2020 00:59:26 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=2, max=100
Server: Apache
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Upgrade: h2
Vary: User-Agent
Accept: application/json
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,zh-CN;q=0.8,zh;q=0.7,zh-TW;q=0.6,fr;q=0.5
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 245
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Cookie: em_cdn_uid=t%3D1594507589043%26u%3D2db560059eea476ea64c1fccc929cb66; memberID=1; memberPassword=c1fe5b5fe410095d9bc71089696c3b58522f8ddc; homepage-tour-hidden=1; memberSession=nM8%2FGzK5XUgwi%2C%26Lk6rfxth%2C23Q%26Xu2N
DNT: 1
Host: [www.heymofas.com](http://www.heymofas.com)
Origin: chrome-extension://mjidoffkbmbfpfibflcnknfklkmcdlma
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: none
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36
grant_type: authorization_code
code: 1adec9ebb3ee4cb360807a30460b9b8250ff473c
redirect_uri: https://mjidoffkbmbfpfibflcnknfklkmcdlma.chromiumapp.org/provider_cb
client_id: u6ezfnsz8c

Comment: It'd be useful if you find out the difference between the local setup and production. Is it the URL of the tab? Do you make this request in the content script?

Comment: @wOxxOm the main differences have to be now the main site is also on a remote server (before both the extension and the website are local?) Haven't really got to the tab url part though. Calling from background script. The other API endpoints can work, just not the authentication part, which is also weird...